# How much memory should 'managed_shared_memory' allocate? (boost)

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess, multiprocess

I'm looking for a definitive answer (if indeed one exists) on how much memory should be allocated when creating a static chunks of shared memory via `boost::interprocess`'s `managed_shared_memory`. Even [official examples](http://www.systomath.com/include/Boost-1_35/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_named_interprocess) seem to allocate [arbitrarily large](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features.managed_memory_segment_information) chunks of memory.

Consider the following structure:

```
// Example: simple struct with two 4-byte fields
struct Point2D {
  int x, y;
};
```

My initial reaction is that the necessary size would be 8 bytes, or `sizeof(Point2D)`. This fails miserably when I attempt to construct an object, giving me seg-faults at runtime.

```
// BAD: 8 bytes is nowhere near enough memory allocated.
managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "My shared memory", sizeof(Point2D));
```

What read/write operation is causing seg-faults? Stack operations? Temporarily allocations within `segment.construct()`? How much overhead is necessary when allocating shared memory?

By trial-and-error I found that multiplying the size by 4 can work for the above structure, but falls apart when I start adding more fields to my `struct`. So, that reeks of a bad hack.

Some might argue that "memory is cheap" in the modern PC, but I disagree with this philosophy and dislike allocating more than I need to, if I can avoid it. I dug around the Boost docs yesterday and couldn't find any recommendations. Here's to learning something new today!

Comment: People might disagree with me here, but I have never in my life coded along the lines of "memory is cheap".  Buying memory is not necessarily expensive compared to how it used to be, but it is very much like money.  The more you have, the more you spend.  Every memory upgrade I've bought for my computer, I've maxed out pretty fast now that i can "run more stuff".  I've always tried to code conservatively in this respect because it is not necessarily cheap *for my application*.  Anyway, just my 2c on that :)

Comment: I agree 100%! And that is the **entire** reason I am asking this question. I only threw that comment out there to dissuade anyone saying "who cares, just allocate 1k and be done with it." I'll try to make it more clear in the post.

Comment: Ah ok :)  "Some might argue" is much better!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this paragraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/interprocess/architecture.html#interprocess.architecture.architecture_algorithm_to_managed.architecture_memory_algorithm) of the documentation :

> The memory algorithm is an object that
>   is placed in the first bytes of a
>   shared memory/memory mapped file
>   segment.

Layout of the memory segment :

```
 ____________ __________ ____________________________________________  
|            |          |                                            | 
|   memory   | reserved |  The memory algorithm will return portions | 
| algorithm  |          |  of the rest of the segment.               | 
|____________|__________|____________________________________________|
```

The library has an extra memory overhead sitting at the beginning of the segment, thus occupying a few bytes of your requested size. According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/e400e710f620fa1a/2451d7b2c606fdf0) and [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/60995), this exact number of additional bytes cannot be determined :

> You can't calculate it, because there
>   are memory allocation  bookeeping and
>   fragmentation issues that change in
>   runtime depending on  your
>   allocation/deallocation pattern. And
>   shared memory is allocated by  pages
>   by the OS (4K on linux 64k on
>   windows), so any allocation will be 
>   in practice allocated rounded to a
>   page:
>
> ```
>     managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "name", 20);
> ```
>
> will waste the same memory as:
>
> ```
>     managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "name", 4096);
> ```

Comment: Good job finding that old post; I searched for quite a while and came up dry. So, by "indeed" do you mean that **there is no concrete answer?** That's what I get from Ion Gaztañaga's response... Also, thanks for that link to the Boost docs. The memory map ASCII art helps out, though I had no luck in programmatically determining `memory algorithm` + `reserved`. But ultimately, it's a moot point since my actual implementation stores 5-10 structure instances (also mentioned by Gaztañaga). Still, this seems like a valid question, even if it's mostly "academic."

Comment: Ah, *there* we go. I knew OS page size must be a relevant detail; the quote above confirms my suspicions. It looks like "best guess" allocation will have to do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Something like using the OS'es memory page size works. In my case this works..

```
off_t size = sizeof(class1) + (sizeof(class2) * 3);
// round up to the OS page size.
long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
size = ((size / page_size) + (size % page_size ? 1 : 0)) * page_size;
```

Using boost::managed_shared_memory allows you to construct objects in the resulting space. Something like....

```
shared_memory_object::remove(m_name.c_str());
m_shared.reset(new managed_shared_memory(create_only, "myspace", size));
m_class1 = m_shared->construct<class1>("class1")();
m_class2 = m_shared->construct<class2>("class2")[3]();
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea of rounding up to system page size. However, it still looks like we're creating an **arbitrary amount of padding**. In this case "3" -- three times `sizeof(class2)`. Am I correct? I've since moved on to other projects, but I'm still interested in the best way to allocate shared memory with the least amount of waste.

Comment: I can't see anyway to get around using the page size for the shared memory area. (Fixed a bug in the second bit of code.)

However you can do the type of suballocation that I was using in the second bit of code inside of the shared memory area. 

look at http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/interprocesscommunication.html#interprocesscommunication_managed_shared_memory gives a pretty good idea of the many ways that sub-allocation can be done.

I'd better learn this editor so I can link more cleanly *sigh*