# Storing contiguous bytes of a POD type in boost interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am trying to create a POD struct type and keep a vector of that struct in boost interprocess shared memory. What I have been doing and it's been working:

```cpp
template <typename T>
    using Alloc = ipc::allocator<T, ipc::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
using String = ipc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

struct SharedData
{
    template <typename Alloc>
    SharedData(size_t aSize, std::string_view aStr, Alloc alloc) : sz(aSize), data(aStr, alloc) {}

    size_t  sz;
    String  data;
};
```

I go ahead and create a vector of this struct which is cool and works, but I wanted to get cache locality when accessing i'th index of the vector. For that I wanted to get, `data` to be present in the same contiguous storage of the vector, so I changed the struct to:

```cpp
struct SharedData
{           
    SharedData(size_t aSize) : sz(aSize) {}
    size_t  sz;
    char data[MAX_DATA_SIZE];
};
```

But this does not get allocated in the vector, when I create it using:

```
auto shared_vec = segment_.construct<Vector<SharedData>>((const char *) shared_vec_name.c_str())(segment_.get_segment_manager());
for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    (*shared_vec).emplace_back(max_data_size);
```

It throws:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::bad_alloc'
  what():  boost::interprocess::bad_alloc
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? I want to allocate a vector of POD type with cache locality as well, since String will have further dynamic allocations which is not desirable for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

`char data[MAX_DATA_SIZE];` makes `sizeof(SharedData)` much larger. Depending on allocation pattterns the vector might reserve or reallocate running out of space in your segment.

Note that many string implementations have [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring), which means you may already have cache locality.

If you're really striving for POD data and complete cache control, I'd suggest switching to something like

```
 std::array<SharedData, N> instead_of_vector;
```

for some fixed capacity `N`. In that case you wouldn't need a managed segment, so consider using `boost::interprocess::mappped_region` directly instead of `managed_shared_memory`.

Note that there are many ways in between as well. Thinking of `boost::static_vector` or `boost::small_vector`. Also, consider that **simply doing a `.reserve()` up-front may solve your problems:

- [Bad alloc is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287171/bad-alloc-is-thrown/21287572#21287572)

  [image]
- [boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file deque of strings runs out of space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915202/boostinterprocessmanaged-mapped-file-deque-of-strings-runs-out-of-space/69917480#69917480)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I love the boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory, how it ties shared memory usage with being pragmatic. I will stick to its usage for now. Also, I think emplacing step by step needs more memory than directly reserving objects at a go! And it actually helped. I switched to .reserve / .resize and it works perfectly.